# Where does IIS intend developers to put additional websites?

Tags: iis, iis-7, web, windows-server-2008-r2

On a fresh install of Windows Server 2008 R2 with IIS 7, it creates a default website in `C:\inetpub\wwwroot`. I'm sure there's lots of subjective opinion on where good places to store website files are, but I'm wondering if I were to create a second website, in addition to the default website, where would the IIS developers have intended I put it?

I'm thinking `C:\inetpub\mysecondsite`, but I can't say for sure.

Answer (score 5):

You can really put your new web site's files wherever you want on the server. Most people tend to make subfolders for each individual site under the wwwroot. I usually delete the Default Web Site and start from scratch.

For example:
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myfirstsite
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysecondsite